# Cannot keep multi-row added old values when validation failed - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How to keep multi-row added old values when validation failed? I tried as follows.

Here is create.blade.php

```
<td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][company]" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="{{ old('addmore[0][company]') }}" /></td>
```

Here is the way I have validated.

```
$request->validate([
    'addmore.*.company' => 'required',
]);
```

All added values remove when validation fails. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't use ajax request? Am I right?

Comment: How are you doing your validation? Are you doing a regular GET/POST form submit, or are you using AJAX? If the page refreshes when you submit your form, that's why your added elements are disappearing. You'll need to do the validation with an asynchronous method, AJAX, to ensure the DOM is not reloaded.

Comment: @zeterain - Updated the question with my validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use dot-notation for `old`: `addmore.0.company`:

```html
<input ... value="{{ old('addmore.0.company') }}"
```

Comment: Wow. It is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: wha if we dont know the numbers of appended rows added via Jquery ,how we can maitain the old values